# Default Dell repo for XPS13 9343

Tags: ppa, xps

I've installed from scratch Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 9343. I remember there were some Dell repos in the preinstalled system, but I'm not able to find them anywhere online.

Do you know which are they? Is something useful in there (some hardware specific driver)?

Comment: There are these two, but I can not find the GPG keys. Help is welcome. http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-dino2-mlk http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell

Answer (score 1):

DELL repositories are hosted on Launchpad.

Meanwhile the [DELL XPS 13 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/ubuntu/dellxps) is obsolete.

You can use the [Sputnik Kernel PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/sputnik-kernel) instead.

But do you need the outdated Sputnik PPA ?

Ubuntu kernels perfectly support DELL XPS.

Additionally available -> [DELL Recovery PPA](https://launchpad.net/dell-recovery)

Comment: Sorry, but also the Sputnik Kernel seems quite obsolete to me, it has linux 3.5 while I've installed 4.4.0-12-generic, and last serie on that PPA is precise, which is quite old...

Comment: @rpadovani : I found another DELL PPA and updated the answer ... Kernel 4.4 is currently not available, because Ubuntu 16.04 until now is not finally released ... maybe the Sputnik PPA will be updated later. :)

Comment: well, thanks for all the infos, but I'm not sure any of these is the one set as default out of the box on xps 13, and I'm curious of which one is...

Comment: @rpadovani : Meanwhile you don't have to add any PPA anymore to your system ... I think it was necessary only when the DELL XPS was a very new product - the only DELL specific thing would be the recovery tool.

Comment: Unfortunately there are plenty of problems with Ubuntu and XPS 13. I've got a 9333 that shipped with 12.04 LTS. I had the bad idea of uploading it to 16.04 LTS and a lot of things got broken, like the headphone plug and worse even the touchpad. I assume these issues would be solved by an official Dell-approved release of 16.04, to be downloaded from a Dell rep.